# printing variables from config

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my requirement the list is dynamically creating with collection of dictionaries with different columns for each time. So every time what I need to print will be different based on the some logic.

If I create **if ..else** statement for each case I can print what ever I want.

Here I have too many cases so I don't want to write that many **if ...else** statements just to print.

Instead of that I want to read what I need to print from a config file and print the actual value.

Example:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'xyz', 'age' : 22, 'place' : 'huj'}, 
         {'name' : 'hjhd', 'age' : 44, 'place' : 'wer'}]
```

want to print name and age columns

the following code will do my work.

```
if id == 1:
    for i in list1:
        i['name']+","+i['age']
elif id == 2:
    for i in list1:
        i['account']+","+i['spend']
elif id == 3:
    for i in list1:
        i['percentage']+","+i['rank']
```

I just want to write only one if else statement. Since I have more than 100 cases.

Instead of writing these many if else statements is there any other way I can handle this by using Config Parser or any thing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you even need `id`, just store a list of needed keys:

```
needed_keys = ['name', 'age']

for i in list1:
    print(','.join(str(i.get(key, '')) for key in needed_keys))
```

`needed_keys` can be read from your config file.

Make sure to use `try-except` or use `.get` (like in the above example) so non-existing keys will not cause an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your code:

```
if id == 1:
    for i in list1:
        i['name']+","+i['age']
elif id == 2:
    for i in list1:
        i['account']+","+i['spend']
elif id == 3:
    for i in list1:
        i['percentage']+","+i['rank']
```

The one thing that leaps out as being repeated *without changing at all* is the `for` statement. Let's invert the structure and merge those statements together. I notice that if I use your example data, all those 
ints have to be converted to strings first:

```
for i in list1:
    if id == 1:
        output = i['name']+","+str(i['age'])
    elif id == 2:
        output = i['account']+","+str(i['spend'])
    elif id == 3:
        output = i['percentage']+","+str(i['rank'])
```

That simplifies things enough that you might be happy with them. But we can do better! Notice that you are looking up a set of fields based on the `id` variable. You don't have a case for `id = 0`, but you do have everything else packed together nicely: 1, 2, 3. So there are two data structures you could use: a list, or a dict.

```
fields_by_id = [
    None, # 0
    ( 'name', 'age' ),
    ( 'account', 'spend' ),
    ( 'percentage', 'rank' ),
]
```

Or you could use a dict:

```
fields_by_id = {
    1: ( 'name', 'age' ),
    2: ( 'account', 'spend' ),
    3: ( 'percentage', 'rank' ),
}
```

Either way, you look up the `id` and you get a *tuple* of strings that are field names:

```
fields = fields_by_id[id]
```

And you can access the elements of a tuple by index (0 or 1, in this case):

```
f0 = fields[0]  # name, account, percentage
f1 = fields[1]  # age, spend, rank

for i in list1:
    output = i[f1] + "," + str(i[f2])
```

Going a little farther, you may elect to use built-in python string handling to manage your output format:

```
for i in list1:
    output = "{}, {}".format(i[f1], i[f2])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
keys = [['name','age'],['account','spend'],['percentage','rank']]
for i in list1:
    print(','.join(i[key] for key in keys[id-1]))
```